# Firebase iOS recover password

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can I recover password if I am using Firebase as authentication in my application written in swift. If user forgot password how can I implement its recovery?

Comment: Firebase Authentication (like any good password authentication system) doesn't store the user's passwords, since that would be disastrous when compromised. Instead it stores a (salted, bcrypted) hash of the password. While that is more secure, it means that it can't send users their actual password in case they lose it. To regain access to their account, a user will have to *reset* their password, which involves sending a "temporary password" to their registered email address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> you should use reset password method like below

```
        Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail:"email@email.com" { error in


     if error != nil 
    {

                    // Error - Unidentified Email
    }
     else
    {

                    // Success - Sent recovery email
    }

 }
```

Comment: And for instance if I dont want to resent I just forgot password, is reset the only way out?

Comment: in any forgot password case  you need to reset  , they never send you your password.

Comment: I think there is no other way except reset.